# win32api and python causing my screen to go black when it moves the mouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, emulation, sendinput

For whatever reason the screen is going black after the second or third movement of the mouse. First is the function i use to move the mouse:

```
import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput


def MoveMouse(x, y):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    x = int(x*(65536/ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0))+1)
    y = int(y*(65536/ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1))+1)
    ii_.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, 0x0001 | 0x8000, 1, ctypes.pointer(extra))
    x = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(0), ii_)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))
```

this causes the screen to go black

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time
import win32api, win32con
from directkeys import PressKey,ReleaseKey, W, A, S, D, MoveMouse
from grabscreen import grab_screen
x_pad = 0
y_pad = 0
def left():
    PressKey(W)
    PressKey(A)
    #ReleaseKey(W)
    ReleaseKey(D)
    #ReleaseKey(A)
    time.sleep(.9)
    ReleaseKey(A)
def leftClick():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    print ("Click.")
def mousePos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1]))
def screen_record(): 
    last_time = time.time()
    while(True):
        # 800x600 windowed mode for GTA 5, at the top left position of your main screen.
        # 40 px accounts for title bar. 
        printscreen =  grab_screen(region=(0,40,800,640))
        #rgb_im = printscreen.convert('RGB')
        pixels =int(printscreen[300, 300, 0]) 
        print(pixels)
        #r, g, b = printscreen.getpixel((551, 350 ))
        if pixels == 255:
            #if r == 127and g == 26 and b == 25:
            x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
            #x += 44
            time.sleep(1)
            MoveMouse(x, y)
            time.sleep(1)
#


        #print (r, g, b)
screen_record()
```

Thanks any help would be appreciated. To summarize i need help determining why the Move Mouse function is causing my entire desktop monitor to black out until the function is no longer being used.

Comment: I should mention it is a similar issue to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674827/python-mouse-movement-emulation-in-games/29956868#29956868  i am trying to run it inside a video game. but it also doesnt work when im using it on the desktop alone. pyautogui wont work. I am in python 3.5 and windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, try changing in:

```
ii_.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, 0x0001 | 0x8000, 1, ctypes.pointer(extra))
```

the fifth parameter (I.E. "1") to a 0, so it looks like this:

```
ii_.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, 0x0001 | 0x8000, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
```

Worked for me...
Good luck